# How to add TikTok button to the footer of a Mosaico template?

Tags: mosaico, social-media, header-footer

The TikTok social button is not available in de predefined socials of the Mosaico social block. Is there a way to add other predefined buttons in the footer like TikTok?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answer of [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39953/create-customized-block-in-mosaico/39955) question. You can do this with a custom base template.