# Convert Mosaico Mailing into template

Tags: civimail, mosaico

Sorry if this is a noob question, but is there a way to convert a used Mosaico Mailing into a Mosaico template?

Thanks in advance

P.S. - I know I can re-use the mailing, but I'd rather create a generic template from the already used example.

**EDIT**: to be more precise, what I did was (all from GUI, no coding):

1. Created a new template from versafix-1: let's call it Newsletter
   Template
2. Created a mailing based on Newsletter Template
3. Updated the mailing with the content and made some changes to the layout
4. Sent my newsletter, all is fine.

What I would like to do now is to apply the changes I made on the mailing to my original Newsletter Template.

Is this possible or do I need to recreate these changes on the template?

I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you well, you have a mosaico mailing originated from a given base template. And you want to use that mailing as a base template. If this is the case, you can do this with defining a custom mosaico base template. The most relevant steps for this are written in the answer of this question: [Create customized "block" in Mosaico](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39953/create-customized-block-in-mosaico)

I hope this answer helps you.

Answer for the edit:

The changes are not sync-ed back to the original template (Newsletter Template in your case). When you select the template on the Mailings > New Mailing form, it creates a copy from the selected template and you make changes only on the copy.
For making permanent changes yo have to do this in the Mailings > Mosaico Templates menu.

On the page you can find the your Newsletter Template in the Configured templates block. Click to Edit and do the permanent changes and then save it.

If you have a draft mailing where the template is already selected, you can remove it with the Reset button and then you can select the updated version of the Newsletter Template.

So if you notice during a mailing that your template needs to be changed, you can follow this workflow:

- Save the mailing as draft, go to the Mailings > New Mailing, edit your Newsletter Template and then save it.
- Go back to the draft mailing, reset the template and choose the updated Newsletter Template.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Glad to know how to create custom templates. However it's not really what I was looking for (unless I misunderstood).
I've updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your issue is a little bit different than i thought. I will update my original comment with the answer.

Comment: just to be clear, after your 'go back to the draft mailing' do you expect it to reshow the content changes they made when they did 'save the mailing as draft'?

Comment: The template content is dropped with the reset only those changes are expected that were added to the Newsletter Template. But the recipient, subject, etc setup is kept. I think it is an acceptable loss if you want to make sure that the important changes are stored in the main template and the current mailing is originated from the latest version of the template.

Comment: So I must go back to the Newsletter Template and manually redo the changes I did in the mailing. I was trying to avoid re-work but I guess it's not possible. Thanks @akosgarai.